# CakePHP Change Data Before Saving to DB

Tags: php, cakephp

So I have the object $this->data['VideoForm']['filename'] in the controller, but I want to  append the return value of getExtension($filename) to it before I save it to the database. This is what I was trying:

```
$this->data['VideoForm']['filename'] = $this->data['VideoForm']['filename'] . "." . getExtension($this->data['VideoForm']['file']['name']);
```

It throws an error when I try to assign it a new value with the "=" or "=>" operator. Any idea of how to do it? I'm sure it's something very simple that I'm missing...

EDIT: This is the error:

```
Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property MediaController::$data has no effect [APP/Controller/MediaController.php, line 31]
```

EDIT: I've continued looking around, and the getExtension() function is definitely returning "jpg" if I upload xxx.jpg, so that's not the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Error: Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property MediaController::$data has no effect [APP/Controller/MediaController.php, line 31]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error is due to PHP 5.2+ change in the way __get() works -- it doesn't return a reference to the value, instead a read-only version.  Cake 2.0+ uses __get() for some controller properties.

The solution in this case is to write to `$this->request->data` instead of `$this->data`.

Ref: [Mark Story's post on Google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/49afb69bde427b33/9ae5c50bd48d3a2b?pli=1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what error you're getting, but I'll reformat your code and let you spot the difference:

```
$this->data['VideoForm']['filename'] =
$this->data['VideoForm']['filename'] . "." . getExtension(
$this->data['VideoForm']['file']['name']
);
```

Comment: $this->data['VideoForm']['filename'] and $this->data['VideoForm']['file']['name'] are actually two different, legitimate indexes of the $this->data object, if that's what you were trying to point out.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to append:

```
getExtension($filename)
```

But then in your code, you use:

```
getExtension($this->data['VideoForm']['file']['name'])
```

Comment: By getExtension($filename) I was just trying to show the syntax of my getExtension() function