# CakePHP unable to save file to DB - Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, upload, blob

I found [a tutorial](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2006/04/15/file-upload-with-cakephp/) showing how to upload a file and store it in DB as blob. This is my code in `FilesController`:

```
$zip_file=$this->data['File']['zip'];
$fileData = fread(fopen($zip_file['tmp_name'], "r"), $zip_file['size']);

$this->data['File']['zip'] = $fileData;

$this->File->save($this->data);
```

**getting this error upon execution:**

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
SQL Query: INSERT INTO `my_db`.`files` (`task_id`, `zip`) VALUES (5, Array)
```

Obviously it's the problem because $zip is an array. How to solve it?

---

**DEBUG:**

`var_dump($this->data['File']);`:

```
array (size=2)
   'task_id' => string '5' (length=1)
   'zip' => 
       array (size=5)
          'name' => string 'Vaja1.zip' (length=9)
          'type' => string 'application/x-zip-compressed' (length=28)
          'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php50B9.tmp' (length=23)
          'error' => int 0
          'size' => int 847624
```

Comment: Have you var_dumped `$this->data['File']` before or after `$this->data['File']['zip'] = $fileData;`? Because after this line it should be a string (well or FALSE), not an array.

Comment: Hm, funny stuff - dumping `$fileData` displays a string but dumping `$this->data['File']['zip']` displays an array. Looks like line `$this->data['File']['zip'] = $fileData;` has no effect. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10204896/1181261) - in short:

I had to replace every `$this->data` with `$this->request->data` and now it works.

Comment: CakePHP 2.0+ changed to using $this->request->data. It's something you need to watch out for when looking at Cake tutorials online as many use older Cake conventions.

Comment: Good tip! Checking for every construct deprecation can be frustrating though.

Comment: @PrimožKralj look at the upgrade shell, it will do most of those replacements for you :)